# How to use generics

Tags: c#, generics

So, I have a class:

```
internal class GridBox<T> : BoxBase where T : new()
{
    public GridBox(Grid grid, GridBoxView view, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button)
        : base(grid, icon, caption, button)
    {
        View = view;
        DataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public GridBoxView View { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<T> DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

I use this `GridBox` `Class` here:

```
public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(sender);
        Grid grid = Extensions.FindChild<Grid>(window);
        GridBoxView gridBox = new GridBoxView();

        return gridBox.Show<T>(new GridBox<T>(grid, gridBox, icon, caption, dataSource, button));
    }
```

I get an error here tho at the `new GridBox<T>`:

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

So, how can I use `new GridBox<T>` if the T is coming from `public static T Show<T>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridBox<T>` has a constraint on `T` that *requires* the type to have a public parameterless constructor. This is what the `where T : new()` specifies. (See the [MSDN article on the new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx))

As such, when you attempt to use it in your `Show` method, the `T` there *must* still satisfy this constraint. If you update your `Show` method to:

```
public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button)
    where T : IComparable<T>, new()
```

By adding the `new()` constraint to `Show`, you will satisfy the constraints for `GridBox` as well.

Answer (score 4):

The generic argument of `GridBox` applies a constraint that you don't, which means that, if this were allowed to compile, you'd be able to pass in a type that doesn't meet its constraints.  The fix is of course simple, add the constraint to *your* generic argument that the type needs to have a parameterless constructor:

```
public static T Show<T>(...) where T : IComparable<T>, new()
```

Comment: All answers are right, but can only choose 1 as an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `new` constraint:

```
public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button) where T : IComparable<T>, new()
```

Comment: All answers are right, but can only choose 1 as an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new() constraint to your static function as well:

```
    public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button) where T : IComparable<T>, new()
```

Comment: All answers are right, but can only choose 1 as an answer, sorry.